# Issues with PHP file from static website hosted off Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Since Amazon offers a great way to run static sites off S3. I am using it for one of the static HTML site which doesn't have any dynamic content. The issue is am using a link.php for one of the outgoing links on the page and when i click the link, instead of reading PHP and redirecting me to external site, it forces me to download the file. Is this becoz S3 can't understand PHP?

Is there any way out? Appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 is just one big storage bucket.  It doesn't support dynamic content.  You would need an EC2 instance to run something that understands PHP.